# Images compressing with wrong colors

Tags: java, image-compression

I using java code for compressing images. Sometimes i am getting image with wrong colors. I don't understand why it's beheviour is inconsistent.

Images downloading from urls

```
 public void imageDownload() {

            String key = (String) map.get("key");
            String url = (String) map.get("url");
    **String imagePath = java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + ".jpg";
    String compressedImage = Constant.COMPRESSED + imagePath;**

        try {
            URL url = new URL(url);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            // Stream to the destionation file
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);

            // Read bytes from URL to the local file
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
                fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            // Close destination stream
            fos.close();
            // Close URL stream
            is.close();

            compressFile(imagePath, compressedImage, key);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.debug("Exception occured while downloading images..." + exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Image compression code

```
private void compressFile(final String inputFilePath, final String outputFilePath,final String fileKey) {

        log.debug("Image file name::" + outputFilePath);
        log.debug("Image key is::" + fileKey);

        final String outputImagePath = tempFilePath + outputFilePath;

        final File inputFile = new File(inputFilePath);

        float quality = FileUpload.getQuality(inputFile);

        log.debug("Image size for url is::" + inputFile.length() + "quality constent::" + quality);
        final File outputFile = new File(outputImagePath);

        boolean s3Uploaded = true;
        if (quality != 0.0f) {
            final boolean isCompressed = FileUpload.fileCompress(inputFile, outputFile, quality);
        }
    }
```

Compression code

```
public static boolean  fileCompress(File inputFilePath, File outputFilePath, float quality) {

        log.debug("File compress with path::" + inputFilePath + "output file path" + outputFilePath);

        boolean isCompressed = false;

        OutputStream os = null;
        ImageOutputStream ios = null;
        ImageWriter writer = null;
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputFilePath);

            os = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
            Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
            writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();
            ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
            writer.setOutput(ios);

            ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

            param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            param.setCompressionQuality(quality);
            writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
            os.close();
            ios.close();
            writer.dispose();
            isCompressed = true;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error("File could not compress due to " + exception.getCause());
            isCompressed= false;
        }
        return isCompressed;
    }
```

getting quality parameter

```
public static float getQuality(File input) {
        long size = input.length();
        log.debug("getting quality constant on the basis of image size: " + size);
        if (size > 768000) {
            return 0.3f;
        }
        if (size > 512000 && size <= 768000) {
            return 0.6f;
        }
        if (size > 256000 && size <= 512000) {
            return 0.7f;
        }
        if (size > 51200) {
            return 0.9f;
        }
        return 0.0f;
    }
```

Destroyed image(image size was before compressing - 84616)
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please provide also FileUpload.fileCompress

Comment: What library are you using to compress your file. Are you reading the file created by `FileUpload.fileCompress(inputFile, outputFile, quality)`

Comment: Can you reduce your problem down to a specific input image and quality?

Comment: I found there, my original file was 80kb but after compression,it is 124kb. am i choosing wrong quality parameter ?

Comment: You might want to check some of the material you get back from, [getCompressionQualityDescriptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriteParam.html#getCompressionQualityDescriptions--) and [getCompressionQualityValues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriteParam.html#getCompressionQualityValues--).

Comment: I've just tested your code that compress the picture it works well on my side. Have you tried with another jpeg file?

Comment: some files of size increasing after compression,i think this is due to wrong compression parameter. can you try please with file of size arround 84616. It is choosing 0.9 from get quality parameter method.

Comment: I've just tested with a file of 84310 and a quality of 0.9f, I get a file of 64773

Comment: OK,can you suggest me other library of compression images in java.

Comment: There is condition on my server when every image is going to destroy...so is this issue related to memory or tomcat ? please help.